# IIS7 Impersonation doesn't work to access TFS repository

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, tfs, windows-server-2008, impersonation

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET page that adds a work item in TFS.

I have enabled impersonation and Windows authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" password="" userName="" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

In the page, I access TFS and try to add a work item:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection prjCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("xxx"));
WorkItemStore store = prjCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
...
```

However, it only works when I select **SpecificUser** in **ASP.NET Impersonation** and store the credentials. It doesn't work when the **Authenticated user** is selected.

I've checked that the SpecificUser is the same as the Authenticated one, but I get permission errors in the latter case (which indicates that the impersonation doesn't work correctly).

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access XXX. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.AsyncWebRequest.ExecRequest(Object obj)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ProcessHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse response, Stream responseStream, WebException webException, XmlReader& xmlResponseReader)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ExecWebServiceRequest(HttpWebRequest request, XmlWriter requestXml, String methodName, HttpWebResponse& response)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.LocationWebService.Connect(Int32 connectOptions, ServiceTypeFilter[] serviceTypeFilters, Int32 lastChangeId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Connect(ConnectOptions connectOptions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.EnsureConnected(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.get_InstanceId()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.InitializeTeamFoundationObject(String fullName, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateServiceInstance(Assembly assembly, String fullName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService[T]()
   at ASP.index_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
```

The following variables look the same for both cases:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
System.Environment.UserName
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Indeed, as John mentioned below, the issue is caused by *Kerberos Delegation*.

[image: Kerberos Delegation]

I've found the following article and accompanying tool very useful in explaining and mitigating this:

[DelegConfig - A Tool To help resolve Kerberos authentication and delegation issues](http://blogs.iis.net/bretb/archive/2008/03/27/How-to-Use-DelegConfig.aspx)

[image: Kerberos Delegation Check]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may have a ["double hop"](https://www.google.com/search?q="double+hop") problem.

Comment: +1 ... just deployed a set of web based ui tools, that interface with tfs, onto "another machine" as a web app on iis. i'm observing the same behavior as that described in this post. any known workarounds? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah. Click the "double hop" link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/280f00b7-5f7b-4330-aa64-3b1625ca6096) article, it's worth a shot to add `EnsureAuthenticated();`

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection prjCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("xxx"));
prjCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
WorkItemStore store = prjCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

I haven't ever tried this, so I can only hope it 'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Who is the app pool for the IIS app running as? By default, I think it's one of IIUSR accounts and not necessarily a domain account with credentials for the TFS server.

Comment: It uses the default ApplicationPoolIdentity, but that's why I've set impersonation on, so that TFS can be accessed with the user's credentials.