# TFS authentication with windows success when run in localhost but error occurred when it deployed in server

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012, tfs, server

```
   var tfsCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.WindowsCredential(), true);
                TfsTeamProjectCollection teamCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(DomainConstants.BASE_ADDRESS), tfsCredentials);
                return teamCollection;
```

I used this for authenticate to TFS from current windows loggedin user and get TfsTeamProjectCollection, It is worked fine when it run from visual studio (localhost), but when I deployed my project in Server it occurs an error

> An error occurred while processing your request

on browser and error log

> Message :TF30063: You are not authorized to access
>   http://unicorntfs:8080/tfs/USP.
>  StackTrace :   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation
>   operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
>   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Classification.ListProjects()    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.CommonStructureService.ListProjects()
>   at
>   UnicornRMS.TimeManagement.Services.TFSTimeManagementServiceImpl.GetAllProjectsByUser(TfsTeamProjectCollection
>   projCollection)    at
>   UnicornRSM.WEB.Controllers.TimeManagement.TimeManagementController.Index(Int32
>   weekNo)

How can I authenticate to TFS from current windows loggedin user

Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446930/connecting-teamcity-to-tfs

Comment: In localhost its worked fine for me, I got error only when deplyed in server

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to a TFS server on your domain then you can use **NetworkCredential** to authenticate:

```
var _credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(_tfsUri, _credentials);

server.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Moreover, try to delete your IE cache and cookies on your deployed server, then try it again.

---

**Update**

This issue may related to **double hop**. Some similar questions for your reference:

- [IIS7 Impersonation doesn't work to access TFS repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695671/iis7-impersonation-doesnt-work-to-access-tfs-repository)
- [Passthrough (impersonation) authentication with ASP.NET and TFS api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013081/passthrough-impersonation-authentication-with-asp-net-and-tfs-api)

Comment: I already have tried this way, thats worked fine. but I don't need to allow users to type and enter their username and password as they already logged in windows. any way thnks for reply @Patrick-MSFT

Comment: Did you clean the user info which stored in Credential Manager on the server first?  After this, it will pop up a TFS authentication window to enter UserName & Password

Comment: Double-Hop may be the root cause. The issue is not related to your code. I also find a related article for your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013081/passthrough-impersonation-authentication-with-asp-net-and-tfs-api