# How do I authenticate using the TFS SDK using a web application?

Tags: .net, tfs, active-directory, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to allow users to do various tasks using the TFS SDK.  I have created a simple .NET web application to do this, which runs perfectly when I'm running locally.  I can connect to the TFS host on our domain as myself using my AD credentials.

My issue is when I publish the web application to another server on the domain, I lose the authentication I had when I was running locally.  I can't connect to TFS as the current logged-in user.

I have turned on Windows Authentication on the web application, hoping to utilize Kerberos, but I still get the following error:

```
[TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://<serverName>:8080/tfs/<projectCollection>.]
```

I am not explicitly passing any credentials to the web app because I want the user that is using the app to automatically log in using their AD credentials.  How is this possible, if at all?  Are there IIS and/or ASP.NET settings that I need to configure to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may related to **double hop**. Some similar questions for your reference:

- [IIS7 Impersonation doesn't work to access TFS repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695671/iis7-impersonation-doesnt-work-to-access-tfs-repository)
- [Passthrough (impersonation) authentication with ASP.NET and TFS api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013081/passthrough-impersonation-authentication-with-asp-net-and-tfs-api)

Also you can  use  **NetworkCredential** instead of windows Authentication to authenticate, but the user on the machine may need to type and enter their *username*,*password* manually:

```
var _credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(_tfsUri, _credentials);

server.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I enabled Kerberos on our web app server and enabled Kerberos authentication on the TFS side, and it still came back with the same error.  I also tried using the credential cache to pass the credentials forward.  I still haven't had any success.